# Convert shutter release from wired to wireless

Tags: remote, wireless, intervalometer

I have a wired shutter release (which I shall call a "remote") that is amazing simply because it's an intervalometer and I love the features it has, never mind that it's a third party device.

However, as I also do sports photography on an occasional basis, I would like to ask if there is a way to convert my wired remote into a wireless one, through the use of an adapter.

My idea is to plug my existing wired remote into a transmitter, with the receiver connected to my camera (Canon 70D or Canon 1000D). The transmitter would simply transmit the signal to the receiver whenever the remote triggers. This means that I can freely use the button on the remote, or the automatic features of the intervalometer.

However I couldn't seem to find such thing online, probably due to that I have no idea how to describe it succinctly enough for a search engine to make sense of what I want. As such, I would appreciate greatly if anyone does knows of such a transmitter-receiver pair device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick would be to find a transmitter that could receive the 2.5mm plug from your wired intervalometer. I'm not sure any such commercial product exists.

It would probably be cheaper and easier to just buy a commercially available wireless intervalometer that fits your two cameras. Either of the two below would do what you want.

[https://www.amazon.com/Neewer-NW-870E3-Wireless-Transmitter-Receiver/dp/B00RHD860O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RHD860O)

[https://www.amazon.com/pangshi%C2%AE-Wireless-Shutter-Release-Control/dp/B01DDAJCKW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DDAJCKW)

Comment: I have the Vello Shutterboss (that looks and works almost exactly like the Neewer that you linked to). One feature that turned out to be *very* important (that both remotes you linked to have) is the ability to plug the controller directly into the camera, bypassing the wireless. This is particularly important for the Neewer (and Vello), because the wireless receiver takes CR2 batteries but the controller takes AAA (pangshi uses all AAA). I have been caught off guard without spare CR2s for my receiver. At least I was able to use the controller directly wired.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if such thing exists either. The main reason that I don't want to get another intervalometer is because I will have a total of 3 remotes then, but I guess I can sell them away. Anyway do you happen to know if both the trans-receiver units of the remotes that you linked have on-off switches? My existing intervalometer doesn't have one, and the battery keeps getting sucked dry. I always forget to remove them everytime I'm done the intervalometer.

Comment: I've not owned them, but judging from the comments/reviews I would say the Receiver has an on/off switch and the transmitter does not. i have a wired version and I've found the batteries last about 2-3 years as long as you make sure the remote isn't set to be actively triggering the shutter when you put it away. It's like a battery operated digital clock or watch. The battery will last a lot longer if it is just telling time and displaying the LCD without a backlight. But if the alarm is going off continuously and the back light is lit it won't last a week.

Comment: One nice feature about the wireless units is the cord can be connected from the camera to the transmitter (instead of the receiver) and the shutter button on it used even with no batteries. If the receiver batteries are dead but the transmitter batteries are still good then you can wire it straight to the camera and still use the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at wireless flash triggers, several models allow you to trigger the shutter release from them. (E.g. Cactus' V6 transceiver)

As the other answer says, the tricky bit will be  triggering the transmitter with your intervalometer, however, there are quite a few adapters of different types which may do what you want.